# Userdata not working in Custom AMI (built on Windows 2019 Base AMI)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am using the Custom AMI built on top of Windows 2019 Base AMI(ami-0fa60543f60171fe3) to create a windows server. But I see the Userdata is not working. This is the CFT I am using.

```yaml
RabbitMQServer:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      KeyName: !Ref PublicKeyName
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref IamInstanceProfile      
      ImageId: !Ref RabbitMQServerAMI 
      InstanceType: !Ref RabbitMQServerInstanceType
      Monitoring: true
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref PrivateInstanceSG
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetID 
      UserData: !Base64 |
          <script>
          echo Current date and time >> C:\test.log
          echo %DATE% %TIME% >> C:\test.log
          </script>
          <persist>true</persist>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows by design, this task is disabled after it is run for the first time for security reasons. To enable it please execute the following command,

```
C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1 –Schedule
```

However, using the persist tag causes Invoke-UserData to schedule a separate task via Register-FunctionScheduler, to persist your user data on subsequent boots. You can see this for yourself at `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Module\Scripts\Invoke-Userdata.ps1.`

**For further analysis**
If you're having additional issues with your user data scripts, you can find the user data execution logs at `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log`(This is a hidden folder)

for other options please refer https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/04/23/re-execute-the-userdata-script-in-an-aws-windows-instance/

Answer (score 0):

Note that User data is processed by `EC2Launch v2` on `Windows Server 2022`, `EC2Launch` on `Windows Server 2016 and 2019`, and `EC2Config` on `Windows Server 2012 R2` and earlier.

The solution quoted in @devanathan is applicable to EC2Config only.

In case of newer `EC2Launch v2` AWS documentation provide a way. By default, the user data scripts are run one time when you launch the instance. To run the user data scripts every time you reboot or start the instance, add `<persist>true</persist>` to the user data.

but if you just want the script to run once next tinme system boots (e.g. you are about to create an AMI out of this EC2 isntance, and you want the new instaces created from the AMI to respect userdata, you need to use `ec2launch sysprep`

```
 <powershell>
  ....
 </powershell>
 <persist>true</persist>
```

ref - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch-v2-settings.html#ec2launch-v2-directory